# помогите не могу понять почему не работает justify-content:space-beetwen;

Tags: html, css, scss

Должно получиться так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.navContent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav-menu ul {
  display: flex;
  gap: 40px;
}

.logo img {
  width: 60px;
  height: 70px;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ujjo</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./image/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Scss/style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <nav>
    <div class="container navContent">
        <div class="nav-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">go back</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">story</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">shop</a></li>
                <li class="logo">
                    <div class="circle-left"></div>
                    <img src="./image/logo.png" alt="">
                    <div class="circle-right"></div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">wholesale</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">clone</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
   </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А почему оно должно работать? И зачем вам столько не нужных обверток?

Comment: в смысле ? там есть список логотип рядом с которым два круга div,в чем именно моя ошибка что не работает?

Comment: f12 жмяк и сразу видно, что уже container не на все ширину, а уже в нем дальше где-то в куче оберток все правильно работает. на всю ширину делайте этот контейнер

Comment: спасибо теперь понял

Comment: И вам достаточно иметь структуру `nav ul>li`.